# How to open a RadWindow using https

Tags: c#, javascript, https, popup, telerik

I have a site where we use a RadWindow as a confirm-popup.

Why does the popup not show/work on "**https**", when everything's works fine on "**http**"?

I can add more code if necessary, but this is the most important, I think. It's where my track ended..

```
string url = "../Controls/General/ScenarieBeregning/ScenariePopupPage.aspx";

        Log.Debug("popup . url: "+url+". "+DateTime.Now);
        string script = string.Format(
"radopen('" + url + "?skemaId={0}&redirect={1}','RadWindow1')",
            skemaId,
            redirect);
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
Page, typeof(Page), "scenarieConfirmPopUp", script, true);
```

I tryed adding "https" in url and google this, but with not luck.

Anyone help is much appreciated.

---

I can share my **solution**:

```
        string protocol = Request.Url.Scheme; // HTTP eller HTTPS
        string url = protocol + "://" + WebConfigConstant.HostAppsetting +"/Controls/General/ScenarieBeregning/ScenariePopupPage.aspx";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/window/rad-window-is-not-closing-with-https.aspx) 

Telerik team :

> The behavior that you experience is expected - if one of the pages is
>   using HTTP and the other - HTTPS, you cannot access objects in one
>   page from the other. Please note that this issue is not related to the
>   RadWindow control - you will experience the same behavior if you are
>   using a standard IFRAME instead. There is no other workaround in such
>   scenario than to have both pages using the same protocol, otherwise it
>   would be a major security hole.

Comment: Hi Shaahin, thank you for the answer. I remember reading this earlier when I google around. But I don't get it. So my popup isn't using HTTPS? Do you think that's was is wrong? I can I check it myself?

Comment: Thanks for the insight and turning I attention back to the right thing. I added https and (this time the right) domain (ups..) and it worked fine :)